# Change a Control in Header of an Accordion from a nested Accordion

Tags: c#, asp.net, user-controls, nested, accordion

I am using the AjaxControlToolKit.

I have an Accordion with an Image inside the Header-Template.
Inside the Content-Template there is a nested Accordion.

These two Accordions are each inside an UserControl. So the parent Accordion has an UserControl inside the Content.

If I am changing a specific control inside the nested Accordion, the nested UserControl calles a public Method of the parent UserControl which changes the source of the Image I have mentioned.

I'm doing this this way because I want to avoid a DataBind because it's very heavy loaded.

While debugging it seems to work because the new value is set to the source and will be stored to the next Postback. But the responsed site does not show the new values.

Is there a way to change the values and show it on response?

---

Edit - Here some striped code...

Structure:

```
#Site
 #DocumentationPanel-UserControl (OuterAccordion)
  #InnerDocumentAccordion-UserControl (InnerAccordion)
 #/DocumentationPanel
#/Site
```

Striped Code:

```
<table><tr><td>
 <ajaxtoolkit:accordion id="accordionGrid" runat="server" style="overflow: visible;">
  <%-- Header --%>
  <headertemplate>
   <img id="imgUserExamState1" runat="server" title="" alt="" src="" />
  </headertemplate>
  <%-- Contenter --%>
  <contenttemplate>
   <ajaxtoolkit:accordion id="accordionGridExaminations" runat="server">
    <%-- Header --%>
    <headertemplate>
     <img id="imgUserExamState2" runat="server" title="" alt="" src="" />
    </headertemplate>
    <%-- Contenter --%>
    <contenttemplate>
     ...
    </contenttemplate>
   </ajaxtoolkit:accordion>
  </contenttemplate>
 </ajaxtoolkit:accordion>
</td></tr></table>
```

Now I am calling from inside the InnerDocumentAccordion the Parent, casting it to DocumentationPanel and using the public Property that links to the outer Accordion.
The InnerDocumentAccordion-Control knows the PaneIndex of the outer Accordion it is in, so I can call the wanted Pane directly and find the image (imgUserExamState1) in the header.
That looks like this:

```
AccordionContentPanel acp = ((DocumentationPanel)this.ParentControl).AccordionGrid.Panes[this.ParentAccordionIndex].HeaderContainer;
HtmlImage image = ((HtmlImage)(acp.FindControl("imgUserExamState")));
image.Src = "funny.png";
```

I can change it but there are no changes about the image in the responsed site. I tried to call a public function of DocumentationPanel, so the changes where made inside the same class the outer Accordion is in, but as expected - no success

---

I have tried to Rebind the outer Accordion but it says that no modification can be done while init, load, prerender etc. But it was only a try from the start.

Comment: I've build a workaround by register a Scriptblock from inside the control. This do its work properly but is completly dirty. I am not going to let it like it is currently. It means I still need an idea to do this properly.

Comment: Please use the "edit" button to add your ASP.NET markup to the question (or a stripped down version that demonstrates the structure of the accordion / user control nesting, if it's a ton of markup).  It's just hard to follow the narrative description of how the controls are laid out.